# Filtering/Grouping a list of dictionaries by a list of keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I need to define a function, group_dictionaries, that will take a list of dictionaries and return a list of dictionaries which contain the same values for EACH key of the list of keys. The "lonely" dictionaries will be deleted.

Here is an example:

```
my_list=[
    {'id':'id1', 'key1':value_x, 'key2': value_y, 'key3':value_z},
    {'id':'id3', 'key2 :value_u, 'key3': value_v},
    {'id':'id2', 'key1':value_x, 'key3':value_z, 'key4': value_t},
    {'id':'id4', 'key1':value_w, 'key2':value_s, 'key3':value_v}
]

group_dictionary(my_list, list_of_keys=['key1', 'key3'])

#result: the only dictionaries that have key1 AND key3 in common are:
[
    {'id':'id1', 'key1':value_x, 'key2': value_y, 'key3':value_z, 'group':0},
    {'id':'id2', 'key1':value_x, 'key3':value_z, 'key4': value_t, 'group':0}
]

group_dictionary(my_list, list_of_keys=['key3'])

#result the dictionaries that have key3 in common are divided in two groups
#of different values: group 0 has value_z and group1 has value_v

[
    {'id':'id1', 'key1':value_x, 'key2': value_y, 'key3':value_z, 'group':0},
    {'id':'id2', 'key1':value_x, 'key3':value_z, 'key4': value_t, 'group':0},
    {'id':'id3', 'key2 :value_u, 'key3': value_v, 'group':1},
    {'id':'id4', 'key1':value_w, 'key2':value_s, 'key3':value_v, 'group':1}
]
```

As you can see:

1. The function creates a key labeled 'Group' which is an integer
   starting from 0. This key is assigned to each "group" of dictionaries
   (by group I mean dictionaries whose keys corresponding to the list
   of keys match exactly for EACH key)
2. The function deletes the dictionaries which don't have "groups".
3. The existing data set on which I am working contains a UNIQUE id for
   each dictionary. This may be useful to create the function.
4. Non existing keys prevent a dictionary from being candidate.

I am concerned about run-time; the actual list contains 80,000 dictionaries of 35 keys each in average. The complexity of the algorithm is likely to be n² (80,000²). Any optimization in the code is welcome.

Comment: It is:
my_list[3]={'id':'id2', 'key1':value_x, 'key3':value_z, 'key4': value_t}
And in the first output it's the second element. 'group':0 has been added.

Comment: Your algorithm definitely doesn't need to be O(n^2); simply maintain a data structure that will allow you to uniquely identify group ids from a set of key/value pairs

Comment: @DSM ok sorry. They both have key1 and key3, but of different values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this will work, it's written in Python3, I haven't optimized it, but it could be a good starting point if it's not fast enough.

```
list_of_dicts = [
{'id':'id1', 'key1':'value_x', 'key2': 'value_y', 'key3':'value_z'},
{'id':'id3', 'key2' :'value_u', 'key3': 'value_v'},
{'id':'id2', 'key1':'value_x', 'key3':'value_z', 'key4': 'value_t'},
{'id':'id4', 'key1':'value_w', 'key2':'value_s', 'key3':'value_v'}
]

# Since we can't have objects as keys, make the values we're looking for into a string, and use that as the key.
def make_value_key(d, list_of_keys):
    res = ""
    for k in list_of_keys:
        res += str(d[k]) 
    return res

def group_dictionary(list_of_dicts, list_of_keys):
    group_vals = {}
    current_max_group = 0
    dicts_to_remove = []
    for i,d in enumerate(list_of_dicts):
        # If dict doesn't have all keys mark for removal.
        if not all(k in d for k in list_of_keys):
            dicts_to_remove.append(i)
        else:
            value_key = make_value_key(d, list_of_keys)
            # If value key exists assign group otherwise make new group.
            if value_key in group_vals:
                d['group'] = group_vals[value_key]
            else:
                group_vals[value_key] = current_max_group
                d['group'] = current_max_group
                current_max_group += 1

    list_of_dicts = [i for j, i in enumerate(list_of_dicts) if j not in dicts_to_remove]
    return list_of_dicts

list_of_keys=['key1','key3']

print(group_dictionary(list_of_dicts, list_of_keys))
print()
list_of_keys=['key3']

print(group_dictionary(list_of_dicts, list_of_keys))
```

Output:

```
[{'key3': 'value_z', 'key1': 'value_x', 'group': 0, 'key2': 'value_y', 'id': 'id1'}, 
{'key3': 'value_z', 'key1': 'value_x', 'key4': 'value_t', 'group': 0, 'id': 'id2'}, 
{'key3': 'value_v', 'key1': 'value_w', 'group': 1, 'key2': 'value_s', 'id': 'id4'}]

[{'key3': 'value_z', 'key1': 'value_x', 'group': 0, 'key2': 'value_y', 'id': 'id1'}, 
{'group': 1, 'key3': 'value_v', 'key2': 'value_u', 'id': 'id3'}, 
{'key3': 'value_z', 'key1': 'value_x', 'key4': 'value_t', 'group': 0, 'id': 'id2'}, 
{'key3': 'value_v', 'key1': 'value_w', 'group': 1, 'key2': 'value_s', 'id': 'id4'}]
```

**Optimization 1:**

Instead of iterating all keys to check if they exist, instead we can just fail while making the value-key and return an empty string, which would mark the dict for deletion:

```
def make_value_key(d, list_of_keys):
    res = ""
    for k in list_of_keys:
        if not k in d:
            return ""
        res += str(d[k]) 
    return res

def group_dictionary(list_of_dicts, list_of_keys):
    group_vals = {}
    current_max_group = 0
    dicts_to_remove = []
    for i,d in enumerate(list_of_dicts):
        value_key = make_value_key(d, list_of_keys)
        if value_key == "":
            dicts_to_remove.append(i)
            continue
        if value_key in group_vals:
            d['group'] = group_vals[value_key]

        else:
            group_vals[value_key] = current_max_group
            d['group'] = current_max_group
            current_max_group += 1

    list_of_dicts = [i for j, i in enumerate(list_of_dicts) if j not in dicts_to_remove]
    return list_of_dicts
```

**Groups have to bigger than 1:**

This uses a second dict to keep track of group sizes, and then checks whether groups are smaller than 2 to mark them for removal.

```
def make_value_key(d, list_of_keys):
    res = ""
    for k in list_of_keys:
        if not k in d:
            return ""
        res += str(d[k]) 
    return res

def group_dictionary(list_of_dicts, list_of_keys):
    group_vals = {}
    group_count = {}
    current_max_group = 0
    indices_to_remove = []
    for i,d in enumerate(list_of_dicts):
        value_key = make_value_key(d, list_of_keys)
        if value_key == "":
            indices_to_remove.append(i)
            continue
        if value_key in group_vals:
            d['group'] = group_vals[value_key]
            # Second group member seen, remove from count dict. 
            group_count.pop(d['group'], None)
        else:
            group_vals[value_key] = current_max_group
            d['group'] = current_max_group
            # First time seen, add to count dict.
            group_count[current_max_group] = i
            current_max_group += 1

    indices_to_remove.extend(group_count.values())
    return [i for j, i in enumerate(list_of_dicts) if j not in indices_to_remove]
```

*Output:*

```
[{'key2': 'value_y', 'group': 0, 'id': 'id1', 'key1': 'value_x', 'key3': 'value_z'}, 
{'key4': 'value_t', 'group': 0, 'id': 'id2', 'key1': 'value_x', 'key3': 'value_z'}]

[{'key2': 'value_y', 'group': 0, 'id': 'id1', 'key1': 'value_x', 'key3': 'value_z'}, {'group': 1, 'id': 'id3', 'key2': 'value_u', 'key3': 'value_v'}, {'key4': 'value_t', 'group': 0, 'id': 'id2', 'key1': 'value_x', 'key3': 'value_z'}, {'key2': 'value_s', 'group': 1, 'id': 'id4', 'key1': 'value_w', 'key3': 'value_v'}]
```

**Optimization 2:**

You can go from `O(n^2)` (loop through the dict list once to calculate and once to delete) to `O(n*m log m)` (loop through the dict list once and loop through sorted removed indices):

```
def make_value_key(d, list_of_keys):
    res = ""
    for k in list_of_keys:
        if not k in d:
            return ""
        res += str(d[k]) 
    return res

def group_dictionary(list_of_dicts, list_of_keys):
    group_vals = {}
    group_count = {}
    current_max_group = 0
    indices_to_remove = []
    for i,d in enumerate(list_of_dicts):
        value_key = make_value_key(d, list_of_keys)
        if value_key == "":
            indices_to_remove.append(i)
            continue
        if value_key in group_vals:
            d['group'] = group_vals[value_key]
            # Second group member seen, remove from count dict. 
            group_count.pop(d['group'], None)
        else:
            group_vals[value_key] = current_max_group
            d['group'] = current_max_group
            # First time seen, add to count dict.
            group_count[current_max_group] = i
            current_max_group += 1

    indices_to_remove.extend(group_count.values())
    for index in sorted(indices_to_remove, reverse=True):
        del list_of_dicts[index]

    return list_of_dicts
```

Comment: Thanks but that's not the intended behavior. The 'id4' dictionary has indeed the keys key1 and key3, but it's the only one. So it should disappear.
The first output should only be:
[
{'key3': 'value_z', 'key1': 'value_x', 'group': 0, 'key2': 'value_y', 'id': 'id1'}
{'key3': 'value_z', 'key1': 'value_x', 'key4': 'value_t', 'group': 0, 'id': 'id2'}
]
The second output is right, but only because i didn't put a dictionary with a"lonely" key3, because then it would be put in group2, and I don't want to.

Comment: Ah so a group needs to have multiple members?

Comment: Updated my question, it maintains the first optimization but loses the second.

Comment: Yes a group needs to have multiple members. there can't be a unique dictionary with the "group" value of 1.

Comment: Yes! That's exactly the intended result. Thanks a lot.
You forgot to put make_value_key(d, list_of_keys) in your last code.

Comment: All good - I've added a final optimization to the deletion section which stops you going through the `list_of_dicts` a second time, if you need the extra speed. Also I wasn't including `make_value_key` because it wasn't changing past the first optimization - but I've added it to both for readability.

Answer (score 1):

This is straightforward enough; first, you will want some way to easily serialize the relevant data in the dict. I'll use this (very simple) approach, but depending on the complexity of your data you might need to come up with something more robust:

```
def serialize(d, keys):
    return ','.join([d[key] for key in keys])
```

Then, you simply store all these serialized values in a list. The index of the value in the list is the ID of your group.

```
def group_dictionary(dicts, keys):
    groups = []
    result = []

    for d in dicts:
        # skip over dictionaries that don't have all keys
        if any(key not in d for key in keys):
            continue

        # get the serialized data
        serialized_data = serialize(d, keys)

        # if we've encountered a new set of data, create a new group!
        if serialized_data not in groups:
            groups.append(serialized_data)

        # augment the dictionary with the group id
        d['group'] = groups.index(serialized_data)

        # and add it to the list of returned dictionaries
        result.append(d)

    return result
```

Comment: Same comment than @Darkstarone.The 'id4' dictionary has indeed the keys key1 and key3, but it's the only one. So it should disappear. The first output should only be: [ {'key3': 'value_z', 'key1': 'value_x', 'group': 0, 'key2': 'value_y', 'id': 'id1'} {'key3': 'value_z', 'key1': 'value_x', 'key4': 'value_t', 'group': 0, 'id': 'id2'} ] The second output is right, but only because i didn't put a dictionary with a"lonely" key3, because then it would be put in group2, and I don't want to.